# storing an arbitrary date in a variable in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

[This is probably really easy, but I've googled unsuccessfully for far too long]

I want to store a series of dates in variables in Postgres in order to run a series of queries against them:

```
\set SESSION startDate  date'2018-04-01'
\set SESSION reportDate  CURRENT_DATE
```

I then want to run a series of queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM assets
WHERE target_date > :startDate
AND target_date < :reportDate;
```

My variable "reportDate" works fine, but can someone please tell me how to correctly set an arbitrary date as "startDate".  I've tried all manners of escaping the value for the \set command unsuccessfully.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  column "date2018" does not exist
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.22.

Many Thanks

Comment: Try changing `\set SESSION startDate  date'2018-04-01'` to `\set SESSION startDate  '2018-04-01'` or possibly `\set SESSION startDate  "'2018-04-01'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to double single quotes to use it in `psql` variables:

```
postgres=# \set foo 'date ''2018-04-01'''
postgres=# select :foo;
┌────────────┐
│    date    │
├────────────┤
│ 2018-04-01 │
└────────────┘
```

Note about single quotes around whole value.

You could to get the exact variable value using `:'<variable name>'`:

```
postgres=# \set foo1 date'2018-01-01'
postgres=# \set foo2 'date ''2018-01-01'''
postgres=# select :'foo1', :'foo2';
┌────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│    ?column?    │     ?column?      │
├────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│ date2018-01-01 │ date '2018-01-01' │
└────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Or just by `\set` metacommand without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try `to_date` method to convert a string to a date.

**Example:**

`to_date('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: Thanks for replying Petar,
Can you give an example of how to set that into a variable for me?  I can't get either of these to work:
    \set SESSION startDate to_date('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
    \set SESSION startDate $$to_date('2018-04-01','YYYY-MM-DD')$$

Answer (score 1):

I actually never used it, but I think you can SET your startDate like this:

```
SET SESSION myvariables.startDate = '2018-04-01';
```

And then get it's value like this when needed:

```
SELECT current_setting('myvariables.startDate')::date;
```

The "::date" it's because the variable is stored as text and you want a date.

Also, if you do it this way, you can change the value of that variable/parameter by using this function:

```
set_config(setting_name, new_value, is_local);
```

Example:

```
select set_config('myvariables.startDate', '20170101', 'no');
```

Now 'myvariables.startDate' value should be '20170101'.

Hope this helps with your problem.